# Visual Studio 2010 Deployment package

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, package, compression

I want to use this task in the VS2010 Web Application package deployment process to compress the javascript files:

```
  <Target Name="CompressJS">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_JSFilesToCompress Include="*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Compresing Javascript files $(_PackageTempDir)" Importance="high" />
    <JSCompress Files="@(_JSFilesToCompress)" />
  </Target>
```

I tried in some locations like `OnAfterPipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder`, but it won't work. In WDP I used to have it like:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      $(BuildDependsOn);
      CompressJS;
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: what's your current build flow like?  what other targets do you have?

Comment: I have some other targets, like minifiy/merge css and delete some files. I'm using only JS Compression as a test-exmample.

Comment: are your other targets working, or are they all having the same issue?

Comment: No, I'm migrating from WDP to VS2010 deployment. This was my first try

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the BuildDependsOn property group, I'd try to get your target to fire after compile or before drop build.  Check out c:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets for various targets to override.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AfterCompileSolutionDependsOn>
    CompressJS;
  </AfterCompileSolutionDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AfterCompileSolution" DependsOnTargets="$(AfterCompileSolutionDependsOn)">
</Target>
```

Comment: BuildDependsOn was in WDP, that doens't apply for Package Deployment for vs2010 anymore.